# Before I can get JSON file, how can I build correct connection with getting 503 Server Error

Tags: java, json, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I was trying several days to get HTTPS connection right to connect to Yobit public API. I don't know what happen to my code. I have tried so many different examples but nothing works out on Yobit. Those codes and examples I have tried, they either give 411, 503 error or MalFormException:no protocol. Can anyone help me? I have very limited experience with HTTPS or web programming on Java. If any one can provide me solutions and references, I will really appreciate that.

```
public void buildHttpsConnection() 
{
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://yobit.net/api/3/info");
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("user-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; JAVA AWT)");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.5");

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: @Mick
In the https://yobit.net/api/3/info Site, It takes 5 seconds to verify from their side. That's maybe the problem there.

Comment: you mean I need to let my program to wait for 5 second? I will do it now. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Sorry, no luck. I use TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(6) and put it after con.setUseCaches(false)
and it is still 503 error.

Comment: Actually no mike. From the back end, it checks for the request is coming from a browser.

Comment: Check my answer It gives 200 as response for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use "https://www.yobit.net/api/3/info" URL Instead of "https://yobit.net/api/3/info" 
It will give you the same result. You can validate it from the browser Window.

Check below snippet.

```
 try {
                URL url = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL("https://www.yobit.net/api/3/info");
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                try {
                    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                } catch (ProtocolException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                con.setRequestProperty("user-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; JAVA AWT)");
                con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.5");

                con.setDoOutput(true);
                con.setUseCaches(false);
                con.connect();

                try {
                    System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Thank you I am going to do it now.

Comment: Gosh, it really works. It response with 200 now. Thank you so much.